# Передвижение картинки по экрану в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

Начал изучать движок pygame. Пишу очень простую игру "Пинг Понг" и уже написал движение ракеток и границы для них, но не могу заставить мяч двигаться по экрану. Как это мне можно реализовать?

Мне кажется лучше будет мне объяснить как это реализовать чем разбираться в этом коде.

Вот мой код;
ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ: Детям до 12 лет, людям с больным сердцем и беременным женщинам лучше не видеть этот говнокод (О боже где классы? ).

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import sys

x_tf = 250
y_tf = 300
x_ts = 250
y_ts = 20
Weight = 640
Height = 360
Size = (Weight,Height)
speed_b = [3, 3]
color_black = [0,0,0]
img_size = [100,25]
ball_size = 70
x_b = 250
y_b = 150
speed_plat = 5

move_right = False
move_left = False

move_d = False
move_a = False

ballmove = True



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Size),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("My First PyGame Windows")


def Platform_rect():
    platforf_firs = pygame.image.load("img/ball.png")
    platforf_firs = pygame.transform.scale(platforf_firs,
    (img_size[0],img_size[1]))
    screen.fill(color_black)
# ------Second Platform------
platform_second = pygame.image.load('img/plat.png')
platform_second = pygame.transform.scale(platform_second,(img_size[0],img_size[1]))
screen.fill(color_black)
# ------ball--------
ball = pygame.image.load('img/browser.png')
ball = pygame.transform.scale(ball, (ball_size,ball_size))
#screen.fill(color_black)
# -------Blit-------
platform_second_R = screen.blit(platform_second, [x_ts, y_ts])
platforf_firs_R = screen.blit(platforf_firs, [x_tf,y_tf])
ball_r = screen.blit(ball,[x_b,y_b])
pygame.display.update()
#






Platform_rect()


while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    #________ballmove
    ballrec = ball.rect()
    # -------balmove-------
    # -------Движение платформ--------
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            move_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            move_left = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            move_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            move_left = False


if move_right == True:
    x_tf = x_tf + speed_plat
    if x_tf > 530:
        x_tf = 530
    Platform_rect()
elif move_left == True:
    x_tf = x_tf - speed_plat
    if x_tf < 0:
        x_tf = 0
    Platform_rect()
# ------Движение второй платформы-------
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            move_d = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            move_a = True

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            move_d = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            move_a = False


if move_d == True:
    x_ts = x_ts + speed_plat
    if x_ts > 535:
        x_ts = 535
    Platform_rect()
elif move_a == True:
    x_ts = x_ts - speed_plat
    if x_ts < 0:
        x_ts = 0
    Platform_rect()
```

Comment: А и еще забыл название картинок не соответствуют из содержимому ХД

Comment: Здесь видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1-ACw9gBz4
под видео ссылка на код.
Посмотрите и напишите лучше ))

Comment: Спасибо большое и еще может кто знает хорошую статью про ООП чтобы была очень просто и подробно.